# UML: Accessing a Class Attribute from within an Activity Diagram Associated with a class method

Tags: class, uml, activity-diagram

I have a class A with method B and attribute C.  Method B is realized by an activity diagram D.  I would like to access C from within D but I do not know how.

I have tried using "read self" within the activity diagram (and then "read structural feature" to get C); however, "read self" just points to the activity diagram and not the owning class.  I have tried experimenting with the ownership field of the "read self" but got nowhere with it.

What is the proper syntax for accessing C within D?

Comment: Hmmm. from the UML spec: 16.4.3.4: For example, if a ReadSelfAction is contained in a 
behavior that is the method of an Operation, then the context object it returns will be the instance of the owning Classifier of the Operation that was the target of the 
 operation invocation. However, if the ReadSelfAction is contained in a Behavior not owned by any BehavioredClassifier, then the context object will be the instance of the Behavior in which the Action is executing.

I will explore

Comment: My colleague just suggested that you have to "Create Object" action of the class you are working on within the activity diagram.  He said it was counter intuitive.  I agree and remain skeptical.

Comment: Your way of accessing C is exactly how it should work. Creating the context of an activity within the activity would not be possible. What simulation engine are you using? Maybe it has some weird conventions.

Comment: @Alex Scheithauer By my way you mean "ReadSelfAction." I am using Cameo's simulation engine.  I haven't simulated yet; it's the validation tool that is throwing this error.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. If you did not run a simulation, what does it mean to "point to the activity diagram". The readself will only produce a result, when it is simulated. And I'm pretty sure, that the cameo simulation engine will return the context object. What is the exact error message?

Comment: The validation tool was indicating the type the "readselfaction" was pointing to was the activity diagram rather than the class owning the activity diagram.  Mismatched type.  I've tried it again and the problem seems to have gone away.